# SVO Controller F3ZF-12A650-FB with C3W1

Tags: engine, ford, part-identification

1971 Galaxie 351W with AOD converted to injection with GT40 lower + upper intake and SVO controller F3ZF-12A650-FB from 1993 in set-up with software C3W1 :

- Injector size 19 pounds or 24 or even 32 pounds ?
- MAF 70mm or 80mm ?

Both must work with the Ford-SVO controller, the installed C3W1 software was written to smooth and precise match the inlets and outlets of the electronic system to provide a optimised motor operation. But nobody can tell me the factory-SVO system set-up, nor I was able to retrieve factory information.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Can you specify the exact information you're asking about? Reading your question leaves me a little less than understanding what you're looking for.

Comment: So, first question - what vehicle had the “standard” svo setup as originally supplied by Ford?

Comment: @SolarMike F3ZF-12A650-FB C3W1 should be for a 5.0 Mustang GT with an automatic. In which case F1ZZ 12B579 AARM should be the MAF and F1ZZ 9F593 C should be the injector.